# add two variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a fileA that contains:

```
  0012,001650,0089
```

I want to get the sum of column 1 and column 2 and the quotient of column 3 and 60. Using awk I tried this

```
  col1=`awk -F, '{print $1}' $fileA | sed 's/0*//'`
  col2=`awk -F, '{print $2}' $fileA | sed 's/0*//'`
  col3=`awk -F, '{print $3}' $fileA | sed 's/0*//'`

  sum=$((col1 + col2))
  qou=$((col3 / 60))
```

But I got this error:

**apn_processing.sh[226]: col1 + col2: The specified number is not valid for this command.**

Can you give me another solution for this?

Comment: Do not use old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `col1=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' $fileA | sed 's/0*//')`

Answer (score 2):

shell is for sequencing calls to tools, that's all. If you're just doing text processing then do the whole job in awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{
  sum = $1 + $2
  quo = $3 / 60
  print sum, quo
}' "$fileA"
1662 1.48333
```

Comment: how about if i only need whole number (rounded off) for the output?

Comment: @newbie: Then you can use awk's `printf` function with the appropriate format; `printf "%d %d\n", sum, quo` will truncate the fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call awk 3 times to extract the fields:

```
$ IFS=, read -r a b c < file
$ echo $a
0012
$ echo $b
001650
$ echo $c
0089
$ echo $((10#$a + 10#$b))
1662
$ echo $((10#$c / 60))
1
$ bc  <<< "scale=3; $c/60"
1.483
```

In bash math, you can specific a number's base with the notation `base#number`, so you don't get tripped up by invalid octal numbers like "0089"

Answer (score 1):

Especially since you're dealing with floating point arithmetic, I would recommend performing the calculations in awk:

```
sum=$(awk -F, '{print $1+$2}' file)
qou=$(awk -F, '{print $3/60}' file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have reason to want to get the answers into shell variables:

```
$ read sum quo < <(awk -F, '{print ($1+$2), $3/60}' "$fileA")
$ echo $sum $quo
1662 1.48333
```

Unlike `bash`, `awk` has no problem with leading zeros on numbers that it receives as input.  For example, observe that the following works just fine:

```
$ echo 016 08 | awk '{print $1, $2, $1+$2, $1/$2}'
016 08 24 2
```

#### Aside

mklement0 points out in the comments that GNU `awk` will try to interpret numbers beginning with zero as octal, falling back to decimal, if they are program constants as opposed to input.  Consider:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=016;b=08; print a, b, a+b, a/b}'
14 8 22 1.75
```

In the above, `016` is treated as octal.  By contrast, `08`, which is not a legal octal number, is treated as decimal.

Comment: Nicely done; as an aside: _GNU_ awk somewhat ambiguously _does_ recognize octals as literals _inside a script_ (not through input), and falls back to _decimal_ interpretation; try `gawk 'BEGIN {print 010}'` vs. `gawk 'BEGIN {print 08}'`.

Comment: @mklement0 Interesting!  I added that to the answer.